# Two different BeautifulSoup outputs?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I have a piece of code that I made in Google Colab that essentially just scrapes a piece of data from a website, show below:

```
#imports
#<div class="sc-aef7b723-0 dDQUel priceTitle">
#<div class="priceValue ">
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/index-cooperative/'
HTML = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML.text, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'sc-aef7b723-0 dDQUel priceTitle'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'priceValue '}).text
print(text)
```

I need this to run as a py file on my computer, but when it runs as a py file, I get the error:

> text = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'sc-aef7b723-0 dDQUel priceTitle'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'priceValue '}).text
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I was wondering why this happened as it is the exact same code.  All of my packages are at the most recent version as well.

Comment: There could be several problems there. One - that classname is dynamic, so it might be different on your computer. Two - website could be protected, so it might serve some captcha first, hence the element wouldn't be found. Did you try to print out the full response you get with requests?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the trailing space in a class name `attrs={'class':'priceValue'}` because when you run the specified web page through the `html.parser` it corrects the HTML in some ways.
In this case it remove the trailing space that present on the web page, because it doesn't really makes sense to have a trailing space in a class name. Spaces needed when you have more than one class for a given element.

So, parsed web page that you store in your `soup` variable have that `div` looking like this `<div class="priceValue"><span>$1.74</span></div>`. And `soup.find` function actually care about trailing spaces, so it couldn't match the class `priceValue` with `priceValue`

To match the class with any trailing or leading whitespaces you could've used the `soup.select` function that uses CSS selectors to match elements, so it doesn't care about spaces, you could've found element of that class like this (with any amount of trailing and/or leading whitespaces):

```
css_selected_value = soup.select("[class=  priceValue   ]")[0].text
print(css_selected_value)
```

That being said, I'm not sure why your code works properly on Google Colab, never tried it. Maybe will try to dig into it later.